# Slideshow image shows up in front of Modal window - updated with jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog, simplemodal

Kind of stuck here.

Based on Hanish feedback - I have created a Jsfiddle to replicate the issue I'm facing

http://jsfiddle.net/BY4fu/10/

Will appreciate if anyone can help me debug

I am using the following plugin for the slideshow

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/basic.html

Now on the same page I am displaying text in a modal window - when a user clicks on certain links. This is the plugin I'm using for the modal window

http://rmcreative.ru/playground/modals_plugin/demo.html

Now the issue is - when the modal window opens up - the images from the slideshow are on top of the modal window and not behind

Based on dalefrench feedback I tried using z-index - but no luck

`.modal {`

```
z-index:1000;
background: #fff;
width: 600px;
margin: 20px auto;
border-radius: 30px;
border: 6px solid #000;
padding: 20px;  
text-align:justify;
```

}

.slideshow img {
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#000;
    z-index:10;
}

Thanks for your time - appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving your .slideshow element a position value of position:relative and the same for .modal. Then give the .slideshow element a z-index: -1 value.

Updated the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/BY4fu/6/

```
.slideshow {
    height: 125px;
    width: 232px;
    margin-left:20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

 .modal {
    z-index:1000;
    background: #fff;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 6px solid #000;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align:justify;

}
```

Comment: Thanks - there is one small issue - my entire page is wrapped in a container with a background color white - so with that when I use z-index:-1 - the images don't display - might be something silly - but cannot get it to work - here is the updated jsfiddle wrapped around div with background color white - you will notice the images are not showing http://jsfiddle.net/BY4fu/9/

Comment: @Gublooo Okay, I think I have solved it - if you add a high z-index property to the 'shim' element it should produce the desired outcome.

As the 'shim' element is the parent of the modal and has a 'position' value (fixed) it's z-index needs to be set also so that it's child (modal) can be 'raised up' with it.

Here is an update to the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/BY4fu/11/

Answer (score 2):

Z-index will come to your rescue. Also check if your modal position is fixed or if the modal is within an element whose position is fixed. If thats the case make the position of modal to default position.
For more infoormation on Z-index check this 
[link](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/)

Answer (score 0):

How about using z-index? Can you jsfiddle your current code?

`http://jsfiddle.net/Qg5Ts/1/`

```
    .modal {
        position:relative;
        z-index:1000;
        background: #fff;
        width: 300px;
        margin: 20px auto;
        border-radius: 30px;
        border: 6px solid #000;
        padding: 20px;
        text-align:justify;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Hanish - I have created the jsfiddle and updated the question with the link to the same - thanks

Comment: You need to add a position attribute to your .modal dialog. z-index requires a position attribute. Works for me.

Comment: The jsfiddle you provided does not work - the image is in front of the modal window - Thanks

Comment: I am using Chrome browser

Answer (score 0):

Give the modal a higher z-index than the slideshow. Think of z-indexes as layers. 1 being above 0.

```
.modal {
z-index:1000;
background: #fff;
width: 600px;
margin: 20px auto;
border-radius: 30px;
border: 6px solid #000;
padding: 20px;  
text-align:justify;}

.slideshow img{
z-index:10;}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion of z-index - but not able to fix it - I have created a jsfiddle so you can take a look - thanks